# how to convert image into bitmap

Tags: android

hi there i have this code and how can i convert image into bitmap ? i am accessing image from gallery.

```
_GaleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent();

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

               intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

               startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
    protected void onGActivityResult(int GrequestCode, int GresultCode, Intent Gdata){

        super.onActivityResult(GrequestCode,GresultCode,Gdata);

        Uri uriimg = Gdata.getData();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example given to achieve this:

[Pick Image from Gallery](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/05/pick-image-from-gallery-set-to-image.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the image to sd card use this code

```
//Get the root of your sd card
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Folder from sd card
File storagePath = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/fb_image");

//Decode the file from the folder to bitmap
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(storagePath + "/" + file_name+ ".jpg");
```